# Excel totals (sum) for each filter critera (text critera)

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

Currently in Excel 2010, I have a filter (drop down list) setup in Column E row 1 for Location. Within that Location filter there are five(5) different Locations.

What am I trying to accomplish?

When I select 1 filter (lets say Chicago) from the Location filter (drop down list), I want it to display the total Chicago locations from column E (currently 35 rows and expanding) on a cell below (cell number can be anything I can change it).

Currently, I have this formula which works with integers(numbers), but not text.

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,E2:E33)
```

The formula does not throw an error, but the total is zero.

Any idea's on where I am failing? Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: change `9` to `3` in the first argument of `SUBTOTAL` function. 3 is for `COUNTA` which should work for text.

Comment: wow. That easy -_-. Thanks Scott! If you post as an answer I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3 as the first argument in the [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) function.

`=SUBTOTAL(3,E2:E33)`

Click link to learn more about the possible arguments for the function.